# Contour ingress and path matching

Tags: rest

I have a Kubernetes cluster with service A and fronted by Spring Cloud Gateway with routes mapped to the service. There is also an Contour ingress controller to expose the services outside. In service A, there is a REST controller B.java with two endpoints. One with HTTP POST method mapped to extapi/processreq/save with JSON body and another one for HTTP DELETE method extapi/processreq/{deleteid} to delete the record passed as {deleteid}. Both works fine when invoked through Cloud gateway. But when I invoke the save endpoint through ingress controller, I am getting 405 method not allowed error. It seems the /processreq/save is treated for delete end point. I tried the pathType as Prefix, Exact and Implementationspecific for ingress rule. I couldn't get it work. Any other areas to look for issue?